# Libgdx detect pression on a object while moving

Tags: android, libgdx, touch, screen

I have a class A and class B.

A is the object (as a character) and B is the rendering class which have the aim to show A.

I am looking for a way to detect when A is pressed, with normal InputProcessor I can't because it detect touch in the entire screen, I only want detect touch over the object. If I check touch position and "A" position it doesn't work because the object is moving and the values aren't so precise

How to solve?

Comment: why not put a "clear" button on top of the object and change the position of the button every time the object moves. Add the button to the input processor?

Comment: @Fish My object is a circle, how could I do it?